# Excel Online 365 Javascript API Add-in Session Timeout

Tags: office-js

We have developed a Excel Online Javascript Add-in, that uses session variables. These variables keep getting session Timeouts every 15-20mins. We want to know a way to work around it or increase the timeout. According to this page

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sessions-and-session-time-outs-in-a-workbook-in-the-browser-74938c0d-9652-4f10-b87c-1a7682540dfb#__toc241372471
"To prevent a session timeout, you must interact with the workbook. This might include navigation around the workbook, sorting, filtering, or any other activity that you do with the elements of the workbook. When the server detects user interaction with the workbook, it keeps the session active."

Our users generally move away from the page and need to relogin. So it looks like our only option is only to increase the timeout but how do you do this in Excel Online 365?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no session control APIs. You could try doing some simple read operation every so often (timer) to see if that keeps the session alive. The APIs use the same session channel as the app session. So, API interaction may keep the session alive.